# Tasseled Cap Transformation coefficient and Bias Value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, digital-image-processing, value-list

I want to perform Tasseled Cap transformation of Landsat 5,7 and Landsat 8 data manually in ArcGIS. Please let me know where from I can get the coefficient values and Bias values for the following formula
**TC = Coefficient *DN+Bias**
Please share the source too.

Answer (score 1):

The formula that you are indicating doesn't really make sense, since the transformed bands are functions of all the input landsat bands, and not only one. A Tasseled Cap Transformation would usually take the form of:
**Greenness = B1_REF * Coef_B1 + B2_REF * Coef_B2 + B3_REF * Coef_B3 + B4_REF * Coef_B4 + B5_REF * Coef_B5 + B7_REF * Coef_B7**

The input is top-of-atmosphere reflectance, and not raw digital numbers. As such, you'll have to convert to this first.

For the parameters to use in combination with the TOA reflectance data, you can read the following three articles:
[Landsat 5](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~doug/RS5750/assign/OLD/RSE(17)-301.pdf)
[Landsat 7](http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1630&context=usgsstaffpub)
[Landsat 8](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/2150704X.2014.915434)

Below are the important tables from the three articles:
First, the Landsat 5 TC coefficients:

[image: Landsat 5 TC coefficients]

Second, the Landsat 7 TC coefficients:

[image: Landsat 7 TC coefficients]

Thirdly, the Landsat 8 TC coefficients:

[image: Landsat 8 TC coefficients]

Comment: The assumption of top-of-atmosphere reflectance is only relevant for ETM+7 and Landsat 8. The coefficients for Landsat 5 assume DN's.

Answer (score 0):

The table shown for Landsat TM reflectance is for the TM on the Landsat 4 platform. There are coefficients for L5-TM but are only for raw DN.