# Landsat 5, 7, and 8 surface reflectance Tasseled cap

Tags: landsat

I see lots of references for Tasseled Cap transformation for Landsat-8 Top of Atmosphere reflectance.
Is the Tasseled Cap approach applicable for Landsat 5, 7, and 8 surface reflectance data as well?

Landsat 5, 7, and 8 surface reflectance Tasseled cap transformation

Answer (score 6):

I have found these Tasseled Cap coefficients for use with Landsat Surface reflectance data.
Please refer to the source article for applicability to your work.
http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0147121
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not. The parameters for Tasseled Cap transformation are only applicable to top-of-atmosphere data.
Applying the transformation to atmospherically corrected data would not be considered 'correct' / 'intended', but that doesn't mean that it wouldn't work reasonably well. You'd have to try it out and evaluate the results.
As for the multi-sensor part of the question - yes, there are parameters for Landsat 5 & 7 - see [Tasseled Cap Transformation coefficient and Bias Value](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156161/tasseled-cap-transformation-coefficient-and-bias-value)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually, I tried and I applied the Tasseled Cap transformation to  Landsat 8 surface reflectance. How to evaluate my result?. I used this article as reference http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/2150704X.2014.915434

Comment: @Soil2015 - for something like this, you'll likely have to base it on a qualitative assessment, as in, does the 'Greenness' parameter reflect where you see vegetation and similarly for the 'Wetness' parameter.

Comment: I have used the parameters  in land use change detection

Comment: @Soil2015 - then compare the detected changes with each of the input images. Are the identified features actually changes occuring, or not? If you didn't end up with too many incorrect classifications, then it all worked out in the end and using Tasseled Cap on atmospherically corrected data didn't cause any significant problems.